# Infopath 2007 Repeating Table Nulls

Tags: c#, infopath, vsta

I am getting this error: Data Could not be read.  Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

I know the Database has NULL values in some fields.  I just want to handle them and continue filling in the next row.  Here's some code:

rdr is the SqlDataReader

```
if (rdr[EmailID] != null)
{
     //this blows up on this line on the 32nd iteration of the loop when searching for an extended group.
     EmpNewData.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:email", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(EmailID));
 }
 else
 {
     EmpNewData.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:email", NamespaceManager).SetValue("No.Email");
 }
```

I could handle this with the Stored Procedure, but I'd really like to know how to handle this.  Above is one of many iterations I've tried.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  IsDBNull seems to take care of it.  I ran thru the code in debug to check where the ordinal sat. It was 14 in this case.

```
int EmailID = rdr.GetOrdinal("EmailID");

Then when using GetString:

if (!(rdr.IsDBNull(14)))
{
     EmpNewData.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:email", NamespaceManager).SetValue(rdr.GetString(EmailID));
}
else
{
     EmpNewData.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Emp/my:EmpData/my:email", NamespaceManager).SetValue("No Email");
}
```

I hope this will help somebody.